# how to play audio file when imageview is at some position on screen which is moving by accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my project i am trying to play when my image is moving from one side to another side of half of horizontal screen .

i am trying like this

sample code

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
if (imageView.center.x + translation.x > 160 - ballRadius) {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"warning" ofType:@"m4r"];
        NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

        AVAudioPlayer *p =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                           initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
        [file release];

        self.player = p;
        [p release];

        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [self.player play];

    } 
}
```

but my app is crashing when i am trying like this

can any one please help me

regards

Answer (score 0):

Where is your app crashing?  Did you use the Debugger to determine where?

How many times per second is this accelerometer being called?  If you are trying to start the same sound that many times, it may be too much for the AVPlayer.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self; 
    accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f; I'm calling Accelerometer 60 times a second. I figured my app is crashing because previously i wrote ".m4r". And now atleast its not crashing but its not moving the UIImage in device and hence audio is also not playing. what do u suggest me to do now??